# Why is my Kafka consumer receiving a list with a single message instead of multiple messages using Spring Cloud Stream Kafka binder in Java?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

Consumer receives a list containing single msg, instead of more.
After sending 3 messages to Kafka, I start the consumer, which then receives a list of the 3 messages.
below is the yml

```yaml
spring:
  cloud:
    function:
      definition: dataConsumer
    stream:
      kafka:
        binder:
          brokers: localhost:9092
      bindings:
        dataConsumer-in-0:
          binder: kafka-cloud
          destination: data_result
          content-type: application/json
          group: data_result_group
          consumer:
            batchMode: true
      kafka:
        binder:
          consumer-properties:
            max.poll:
              records: 40
            fetch:
              max:
                wait:
                  ms: 5000
```

consumer coded

```java
   @Bean
   Consumer<Message<List<JSONObject>>> dataConsumer() {
        return message -> {
            logger.info(message.toString());
        };
    }
```

Message should be sent if the number of message beyond 40 or time beyond 5s, is my understanding wrong?
How can I to moduify code or yaml to meet it?

Comment: Try with `Consumer<List<JSONObject>>`